# How to get full duplex websocket with Bottle and MQTT

Tags: websocket, bottle, mqtt, gevent

I'm trying to get a "communication line" between a server app that uses MQTT for messaging and a web page where I want to see the messages in real time and send back messages to the server-side app.

I use mosquitto, Bottle and gevent on the server and I want to keep it as simple as possible. Using gevent I managed to receive the MQTT messages in a greenlet, put them in a queue and send the messages to the webpage in the websocket procedure which looks like this:

```
while True:
    mqt = queue.get(True)
    ws.send(mqt)
```

I can also send messages from the web page back to the server and MQTT like this (also through a queue):

```
while True: 
    msg = ws.receive()
    queue2.put(msg)
```

However I want these two loops to work at the same time on the same websocket. Is there any way to combine them? For example does receive have a timeout? I guess I could use two separate websockets, but that would be a waste if I can do it with only one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just have messages delivered directly to the page using MQTT over Websockets? There are a number of brokers that support Websockets and the paho JavaScript client allows both subscribing and publishing of messages

Comment: Good idea, though I don't like much that I have to compile everything since mosquitto by default doesn't come with websocket support :)

Comment: What platform? most prebuilt binaries should have websockets included these days (with the exception of Fedora which I would love to fix)

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and just realized that it comes with mosquitto 0.15. I compiled and now run version 1.4.4. It may be the time to update my server, but i don't have much time on my hands